# How can I use the window1 text box value in the field in the main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, window, bind

I have two windows: Mainwindow and window1. Window1 has a textbox.
Mainwindow has a label and button. When I click the button the value in the textbox will be added to the label. I need cs code, please!

// Mainwindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Name="lbl" Content="0" FontSize="150"/>
            <Button x:Name="mushtbtn" Height="50" Content="Add " Click="mushtbtn_Click"  />
            <Button x:Name="newWindow" Content="Show Window1" Height="50" Click="newWindow_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>

//Window1.xaml

<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox"  FontSize="50"/>
            <Button x:Name="closebtn" Content="Save and close" Height="50" Click="closebtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you update your post to include what you've tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

In MainWindow you can initialize a new window1 x when you click the new window button. After being initialized you can access the textbox text and asign to the main window label.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Window1? x; // added nullable check

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mushtbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (x is not null) // check if window is initialized
        {
            lbl.Content += x.txtbox.Text; // concatenate text
        }
    }

    private void newWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        x = new Window1();
        x.Show();
    }
}
```

In the window1 all you have to do is enter text and then close();

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void closebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to click the add button in the main window.

Comment: Thank you Mr! Can you help me again. Each time I pressed a button, the label had to display the value in the textbox. e.g: For textbox value 2, when I pressed the button, the label displayed 2, 4, 6, 8 ..... that is, it must add 2. I apologize that my English is not good.

Comment: @DavronValiyevich It qualifies for another question. But you need to try something. Please do your own research before asking a question. As the comment mentioned in the question

Comment: @Davron updated with += to cancatenate text

Answer (score 0):

In Window1 I added this code:

```
    private void closebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow MW = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        MW.lbl.Content = MW.lbl.Content + txtbox.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```