# Why does my rectangle not appear in the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

I have this rectangle

```
    var rectangle = new Rectangle()
    {
        Width = double.NaN,
        Height = 32,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        Fill = Brushes.WhiteSmoke
    };
```

Which I add to the mainGrid of the window like this:

```
(mainWindow.Content as Grid).Children.Add(rectangle);
```

By doing this, the rectangle will not autofit to the grid width (it doesn't even appear), however if I add an amount, say 300 to its width, it will appear in the grid at the position I indicated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to create a MainWindow instance first, perhaps this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594380/4095782

Comment: The mainWindow instance already exists, as I said in the opening post, if I set a finite width it will appear in the mainWindow grid, otherwise no.

I tried setting the mainWindow horizontal, vertical, horizontalcontent and verticalcontent alignments in many ways and none of it affected the outcome, I did the same for the mainWindow grid and it  has the same behavior.

Comment: These photos are before and after, so, Double.NaN Width is this: https://gyazo.com/66f92022b9ba7231c30b724e24af7f83, 300 Width is this: https://gyazo.com/ac0b7d5f137987dd82bd7529cd42063c, as you can see, other elements have no issues, but this one specifically has issues.

Comment: You must remove the Horizontal.Alignment.Center setting as it will prevent the element from stretching. It also doesn't make sense from a logical point of view, because when an object stretches to occupy the maximum available space, then there will be no alignment.

Comment: @BionicCode that did it, thank you very much, I had no clue this was the logic, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set both `Width = double.NaN` and `HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center`.

Either assign a value to Width and let HorizontalAlignment to be Center,
Or set `HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` and let Width to be NaN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you answered at the same time as BionicCode, this was the solution, I hope this helps others who come across this issue and learn something from this.